# How to integrate VOLTTRON with Opal-RT?

Tags: python, modbus-tcp, volttron

I am trying to connect Opal-Rt device to VOLTTRON platform using MODBUS TCP/IP communication. I have installed Listener Agent and Master Driver Agent with device configuration as follows:

```
{
"driver_config": {"device_address": "192.168.*.*"},
"driver_type": "modbus",
"registry_config":"config://registers.csv",
"interval":60,
"timezone":"UTC"
}
```

All I am trying to do is to listen to the data published to the message bus at regular interval and write it to the CSV file. What would be the configuration for Actuator Agent? And, how can I launch the actuator agent with provided agent's configuration file?

After installing Actuator agent, how can I request a task schedule to a specific topic for a specific timeslot?

Thank  you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rabindra,

For this use case you needn't use an actuator agent at all. The master driver can be configured with N number of devices using configurations similar to the one you provided.

What is missing from your post is whether or not you've included a registry configuration.
The 'registry_config' value above should reference a CSV defining the relationship the driver should have to individual registers on the simulated devices on OPAL-RT. See the following documentation:

[Readthedocs Modbus Configuration](https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/develop/core_services/drivers/driver_configuration/modbus-driver.html)

Additionally, I strongly recommend switching from the basic Modbus driver to the Modbus_TK driver. It's a bit more robust and full-featured. You can read more about that here:

[Readthedocs Modbus_TK Configuration](https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/develop/core_services/drivers/driver_configuration/modbus-tk-driver.html)

After configuring the devices per the included links, you can install a CSVHistorian from `<VOLTTRON_ROOT`>/examples to store the device data to a CSV.

Comment: I did the configuration as per the instruction provided above. I started my VOLTTRON instance in monitor mode and with listener agent and master driver agent running, I can see master_driver scrapping the device. But, it show me **DriverInterfaceError: Failed to scrap device at 192.168.1.8:22916 Modbus Error: pymodbus returned None** I am getting this error as soon as I send some data from Opal-rt. 192.168.1.8 is my vip_address

Comment: I suspect that the IP and port that you are using may be a bit confused, although it is hard to debug from my end. The IP and port specified in the confugration should be the IP and port of the remote device, in this case the devices being simulated by OPAL-RT. The IP and ports you've listed seem to me to be the default provided by the vcfg command. For context, 502 is the designated Modbus port, so it's very likely to be the port you should specify in your driver configurations. If you continue to struggle, consider contacting the VOLTTRON team by emailing volttron@pnnl.gov.

Comment: Thank you. I had the error with my registry config file. With the config file setup properly I can send data from RT-LAB to VOLTTRON. Now, I am trying to send control signal back to VOLTTRON. How can I configure the VOLTTRON instance to send command back to RT-LAB??